# Query breaking with 'posts_per_page' => -1

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, tax-query

I'm trying to return all posts for a category associated with a custom post type. I have the following query:

```
$cat_name = single_cat_title('', FALSE);
$termObj = get_term_by('name', $cat_name, 'category');
$catID = $termObj->term_id;

$videos = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $catID
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

If I remove the:

```
    'posts_per_page' => -1
```

parameter, the query works and returns the default 10 posts. *HOWEVER, I need to return all posts, not just 10.* When I add that parameter, it breaks the query and stops execution of my page.

**What I've Tried**

1. remove_all_filters( 'pre_get_posts' );

I've tried adding this function before the query, but the query still broke the page.

2. 'nopaging' => true

I tried replacing the posts_per_page parameter with this parameter, but the query broke again.

3. 'suppress_filters' => true

I've also tried adding this parameter in the query, but that didn't affect the query and it still only returned the default 10 results.

What am I doing wrong here that the parameter is breaking my query?

Thanks!

Comment: How many posts are in the `video` post type? Have you tried disabling all plugins? What about enabling the default theme?

Comment: There are over 2000 posts in this video post type. If I deactivate all the plugins it still does not work. If I enable the default theme, my query is no longer in play. As I mentioned, the query functions fine until I add the posts_per_page parameter.

Comment: And how many are in that specific category? Odds are your server can't handle pulling that many posts at once, you may need to [Lazy Load](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/lazy-load) them.

Comment: Over 1500. We do have a lazy load function enabled, but it was setup to run a WP_Query  several times in the page. I was hoping to remove all those numerous queries, converting them into one query and then letting them lazy load for display. I guess what I want is not possible due to the number of posts we have.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the server. I just tried incrementally update the posts_per_page value allowed and it broke at 300 with: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes) ...

Comment: A good pratice to get a high number of rows is to loop on it, instead of making 1 big query. Why don't you loop on it, and append each result to what you wish ? Also, do you REALLY need to get all posts ? you won't display 3000 posts on a page, do you ?

Comment: As has already been said, that's way too many posts - you *can* get around memory limits by "batching up" the query, but still - you gonna list ~3000 items on a page? Sounds like you should paginate or infinite scroll it.

Comment: You should never show all posts, set a maximum, even if it's a silly max like 500 that you never expect to reach, 2000 is a lot of posts to display all at once, even in purely HTML terms, it's likely your server runs out of time or memory displaying them

Comment: Well as I mentioned, we have a lazy load function in place, so all the posts don't show on the page at the same time. We're just queuing them up to show,  like it works for infinite scrolling.

Comment: @random - I'm not sure what you mean. Wouldn't looping require a query each time?

Comment: **Lazy load function?** How does that look like? You should add it to your question. Are you paginating? `'posts_per_page' => -1` and `offset` parameters doesn't work together. 100 small queries is much faster and more efficient than one huge, huge query - one user takes all the resources and might not even look 10 of your posts, what a waste it would be..

Comment: "we have a lazy load function in place, so all the posts don't show on the page" Umm... that's not lazy loading. That's just hiding & showing.

Comment: Thank you all. You've given me a lot to mull over. I clearly need to rethink my approach here. As for this question, since there will be no answer, do you recommend I delete it, or leave it as is?